# image display in asp page

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have one aspx page and two controls one FileUpload control and Image control. When am selecting an image using browse button i want to display it in image cotrol.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display the image BEFORE the file is uploaded to the server (immediately after choosing it in the Browse dialog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest variant (assume that upload control named as MyFileUpload1 and image named as Image1):

```
MyFileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + MyFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/" + MyFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```